# PDF Creation Using PhatomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to generate PDF using PhantomJS. All the examples i have seen so far is to run Phantom JS through command line. Is there a way to invoke PhantomJS and create the PDF when the user clicks on download option for the web page.

Comment: fire the script on "click" using jquery... or...since phantomjs can be run as a function..add the on-click attribute to to the button tag.

Comment: @CarlBoneri No, PhantomJS is not a client-side script. It's a full browser application. You can certainly use jQuery to send a request to the server which would then execute the PhantomJS script in PhantomJS.

Comment: ah..that's correct.